# My iOS App iTunes Connect says preparing for upload. What?

Tags: iphone

Okay so I have completed my iOS app and have submitted it. My bundleID is the same one XCode has generated for me but the app name is different. But I don't get how it works. I have not uploaded any source code and it says the app is complete, preparing for upload. What??? Can someone explain to me how it works? I would post images but have not enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial on this. [How to Submit Your App to Apple: From No Account to App Store, Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1). I suggest you check this out, then ask specific questions if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The most I can tell you with the information that you have provided me, is that it seems that whatever compiler/bundler you are using is probably compiling your source code, and changing your source files into the formats needed for an iOS app bundle.

Honestly, however, there is not enough information here to give a more complete answer, or anything more than a guess. Please edit your question and include more information such as what you are using to write this iOS app. I would have made this a comment, but I don't have quite enough reputation to do so yet.